# Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

I'm using reactive mongodb within a spring boot application, but I get the errors bellow:

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ReactiveMongoTemplate - Streaming aggregation: [{ "$match" : { "type" : { "$in" : ["INACTIVE_SITE", "DEVICE_NOT_BILLED", "NOT_REPLYING_POLLING", "MISSING_KEY_TECH_INFO", "MISSING_SITE", "ACTIVE_CIRCUITS_INACTIVE_RESOURCES", "INCONSISTENT_STATUS_VALUES", "TEST_SUPERVISION_RANGE"]}}}, { "$project" : { "extractionDate" : 1, "_id" : 0}}, { "$group" : { "_id" : null, "result" : { "$max" : "$extractionDate"}}}, { "$project" : { "_id" : 0}}] in collection kpi
    org.mongodb.driver.cluster - No server chosen by com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.ClientSessionHelper$$Lambda$1183/0x000000080129dd60@292878db from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=REPLICA_SET, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=10.235.79.213:7915, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, ServerDescription{address=10.235.79.89:7915, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
    luster - No server chosen by ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary} from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=REPLICA_SET, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=10.235.79.213:7915, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, ServerDescription{address=10.235.79.89:7915, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
    com.obs.dqsc.interceptor.GlobalExceptionHandler - Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=10.235.79.213:7915, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, {address=10.235.79.89:7915, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=10.235.79.213:7915, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, {address=10.235.79.89:7915, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=10.235.79.213:7915, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, {address=10.235.79.89:7915, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=10.235.79.213:7915, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, {address=10.235.79.89:7915, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]]
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

This is my my mongodb config:

```
@Override
public MongoClient reactiveMongoClient() {
    ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString(
            "mongodb://" + username + ":" + password +
                    "@" + host1 + ":" + port
                    + "," + host2 + ":" + port +
                    "/?authSource=" + authSource +
                    "&replicaSet=" + replica
    );

    MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .applyToSslSettings(builder ->
                    builder.enabled(true).invalidHostNameAllowed(true)
            )
            .applyToConnectionPoolSettings(
                    builder -> builder.minSize(10)
                            .maxSize(100)
                            .maxWaitTime(8,TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            )
            .applyToSocketSettings(builder -> builder.applySettings(SocketSettings.builder().connectTimeout(5,TimeUnit.MINUTES).readTimeout(5,TimeUnit.MINUTES).build()))
            .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
            .build();

    return MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);
}
```

I tried to change the timeout using **applyToConnectionPoolSettings** and **applyToSocketSettings** methods, but the timeout still always the same (30 sec). Also I tried to use different networks but nothing changed.

Comment: Have you tried setting the server selection timeout `.applyToClusterSettings(d -> d.serverSelectionTimeout(...)`?

Comment: apparently it was a network issue, after connecting to my company vpn the problem was resolved. thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

After small tries, I discovered that it was a network issue, after connecting to my company VPN, the problem was resolved.